# Change actionbar title font within fragment

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar

Is it possible to change the actionbar title font programmatically from within a fragment. Basically i am using a sliding tab interface and one of the fragments needs to use a different
font family for the actionbar title.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: you have use any library ?

Comment: I'm not sure what to use to be honest or whether this can even be done, as I can't find any information on doing it